# How to transfer the following tensorflow code into pytorch

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

I want to re-implement the word embedding [here](https://github.com/chenchongthu/DeepCoNN/blob/master/model/DeepCoNN.py)

here is the original tensorflow code  (version: 0.12.1)

```
import tensorflow as tf


class Network(object):
    def __init__(
        self, user_length,item_length, num_classes, user_vocab_size,item_vocab_size,fm_k,n_latent,user_num,item_num,
        embedding_size, filter_sizes, num_filters, l2_reg_lambda=0.0,l2_reg_V=0.0):


 # Skip the embedding
    pooled_outputs_u = []

    for i, filter_size in enumerate(filter_sizes):
        with tf.name_scope("user_conv-maxpool-%s" % filter_size):
            # Convolution Layer
            filter_shape = [filter_size, embedding_size, 1, num_filters]
            W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(filter_shape, stddev=0.1), name="W")
            b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[num_filters]), name="b")
            conv = tf.nn.conv2d(
                self.embedded_users,
                W,
                strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],
                padding="VALID",
                name="conv")
            # Apply nonlinearity
            h = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.bias_add(conv, b), name="relu")
            # Maxpooling over the outputs
            pooled = tf.nn.max_pool(
                h,
                ksize=[1, user_length - filter_size + 1, 1, 1],
                strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],
                padding='VALID',
                name="pool")
            pooled_outputs_u.append(pooled)
    num_filters_total = num_filters * len(filter_sizes)
    self.h_pool_u = tf.concat(3,pooled_outputs_u)
    self.h_pool_flat_u = tf.reshape(self.h_pool_u, [-1, num_filters_total])



    with tf.name_scope("dropout"):
        self.h_drop_u = tf.nn.dropout(self.h_pool_flat_u, 1.0)
        self.h_drop_i= tf.nn.dropout(self.h_pool_flat_i, 1.0)
    with tf.name_scope("get_fea"):
        Wu = tf.get_variable(
            "Wu",
            shape=[num_filters_total, n_latent],
            initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
        bu = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[n_latent]), name="bu")
        self.u_fea=tf.matmul(self.h_drop_u, Wu) + bu
        #self.u_fea = tf.nn.dropout(self.u_fea,self.dropout_keep_prob)
        Wi = tf.get_variable(
            "Wi",
            shape=[num_filters_total, n_latent],
            initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
        bi = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[n_latent]), name="bi")
        self.i_fea = tf.matmul(self.h_drop_i, Wi) + bi
        #self.i_fea=tf.nn.dropout(self.i_fea,self.dropout_keep_prob)


    with tf.name_scope('fm'):
        self.z=tf.nn.relu(tf.concat(1,[self.u_fea,self.i_fea]))

        #self.z=tf.nn.dropout(self.z,self.dropout_keep_prob)

        WF1=tf.Variable(
                tf.random_uniform([n_latent*2, 1], -0.1, 0.1), name='fm1')
        Wf2=tf.Variable(
            tf.random_uniform([n_latent*2, fm_k], -0.1, 0.1), name='fm2')
        one=tf.matmul(self.z,WF1)

        inte1=tf.matmul(self.z,Wf2)
        inte2=tf.matmul(tf.square(self.z),tf.square(Wf2))

        inter=(tf.square(inte1)-inte2)*0.5

        inter=tf.nn.dropout(inter,self.dropout_keep_prob)

        inter=tf.reduce_sum(inter,1,keep_dims=True)
        print inter
        b=tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1), name='bias')
```

And here is the pytorch version 1.0 that I try

```
class Network(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(
        self, user_length,item_length, num_classes, user_vocab_size,item_vocab_size,fm_k,n_latent,user_num,item_num,
        embedding_size, filter_sizes, num_filters, l2_reg_lambda=0.0,l2_reg_V=0.0):



        pooled_outputs_u = []

    def forward():
```

I mainly have the trouble with the convolutional layer tranforming.

Pytorch is much easy to use since we can skip lots of `W` and `b` definition. Is there some one can help me with the rest? Thanks

Comment: Why tensorflow to torch, not the other way around?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin, I can find many tensorflow code in github. But I found torch code is much easy to understand. Therefore, I try to practice some tensorflow code into pytorch.  Both of them are very useful. Therefore, I want learn both together. Thanks

Comment: kindly point to the exact line that you are having trouble with I will be happy to assist to convert it into torch.

Comment: @Inder I have some trouble in the forward process: from `pooled_outputs_u = []` to `self.h_pool_flat_u = tf.reshape(self.h_pool_u, [-1, num_filters_total])`, it involving convolutional layer and maxpooling layer which I am not familiar. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pytorch equivalent of the tensorflow part of the code will be, explained with comments in the code itself, you have to import truncnorm from scipy.

```
from scipy.stats import truncnorm #extra import equivalent to tf.trunc initialise

pooled_outputs_u = []

for i, filter_size in enumerate(filter_sizes):


    filter_shape = [filter_size, embedding_size, 1, num_filters]

    #W is just a tensor now that will act as weight to the conv layer
    W=torch.tensor(truncnorm.rvs(-1,1,size=[10,10]))
    #bias initialized with 0.1 initial values 
    b=torch.zeros([num_filters])+0.1
    #conv layer with the same parameters as the tensorflow layer more on this in the link
    conv=torch.nn.functional.conv2d(self.embedded_users,W,bias=b,strides=[1,1,1,1],padding=0)
    #can use torch sequential to include it all in a single line but did it like this for better understanding.
    h=torch.relu(conv)
    #look at link2 for what a max pool layer does, basically it is a kind of feature extraction
    pooled=torch.nn.functional.max_pool(h,kernal_size=[1,user_length-filter_size+1,1,1],strides=[1,1,1,1],padding=0)
    pooled_outputs_u.append(pooled)
num_filters_total = num_filters * len(filter_sizes)
self.h_pool_u=torch.concat(3,pooled_outputs_u)
self.h_pool_flat_u=torch.reshape(self.h_pool_u,[-1,num_filters_total])
```

Reference:

[Link 1](https://adeshpande3.github.io/A-Beginner%27s-Guide-To-Understanding-Convolutional-Neural-Networks/)

[Link 2](https://computersciencewiki.org/index.php/Max-pooling_/_Pooling)

Comment: Good point, I have one more question, we put your code in `forward()` or in the `__init__` ? In tensorflow, the code is in `__init__`

Comment: It seems that you're an expert both in `tensorflow` and `pytorch`. I was wondering if you can transfer `all`  code of tensorflow https://github.com/chenchongthu/DeepCoNN/blob/master/model/DeepCoNN.py, into a pytorch code. For example, how to better original the `__init__()` and `forward()` in pytorch. I think that will be very hepful for beginner. Thanks so much.

Comment: @jason, everything in `tf.nn.functional` is for forward() function, as its ready to use and accepts values. not really sure if I am an expert but I will attempt the conversion this weekend and post the same on github after obtaining permission from the original owner. :)

Comment: Thanks, let me know if you finish the github and attach the link in this equation.

Comment: @jason absolutely sir

Comment: @jason Hey there, are you still up for some translation help?

Comment: @Jubick, Yes, any help is awesome.